# Invariant theory of the definite and indefinite orthogonal groups

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory, orthogonal-matrices, invariant-theory

I am vaguely aware of the following facts:

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional real vector space with a positive-definite inner product $g$. Let $g_{\otimes n}$ denote the natural extension of $g$ to $V^{\otimes n}=V\otimes\cdots\otimes V.$ Let $\rho:\text{O}(V,g)\to\text{O}(V^{\otimes n},g_{\otimes n})$ be the standard group homomorphism. Then

1. The $g_{\otimes n}$-invariant linear maps $V^{\otimes n}\to\mathbb{R}$ exist only when $n$ is even, and they are spanned by the complete contractions 
   $$x_{\sigma(1)}\otimes\cdots\otimes x_{\sigma(n)}\mapsto g(x_{\tau(1)},x_{\tau(2)})\cdots g(x_{\tau(n-1)},x_{\tau(n)})$$
   where $\sigma$ and $\tau$ range over all permutations of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$.
2. If $W\subset V^{\otimes n}$ is a linear subspace such that $(\rho(T))(W)\subset W$ for all $T\in\text{O}(V,g)$ and such that the dimension of the vector space
   $$\Big\{\text{bilinear symmetric }S:W\times W\to\mathbb{R}\text{ s.t. }(\rho(T))^\ast S=S\quad\forall T\in\text{O}(V,g)\Big\}$$
   is one, then there is no nontrivial proper linear subspace $U\subset V$ with $(\rho(T))(U)\subset U$ for all $T\in\text{O}(V,g).$

My reference is chapter 9 in Besse's book on four-dimensional geometry. My questions are the following:

1. Does the above remain true if $g$ is only non-degenerate? It seems like the argument for #2 may break down since it relies on orthogonal projection. I couldn't make a guess on #1 since I'm not familiar with Weyl's book on the classical groups.
2. Where can I find a reference with such a statement? Weyl's book doesn't seem to cover the indefinite case.

Comment: Two references I just found: Peter B. Gilkey "Local invariants of a pseudo-Riemannian manifold", Math. Scand. 36 (1975), 109-130 and section II.12 of Weyl's book seem to suggest that the situation should not be so different in the indefinite case, but I'm not capable of understanding the actual claims made